# What is the official maximum PAB part limit?

Tags: pick-a-brick

I would like to order a large quantity of different pieces from Pick-A-Brick. When I click through Pick-A-Brick and choose all my bricks, it always stops accepting new pieces after I have 95 distinct pieces in my bag.

Is there an official limit to how many distinct parts I can order from Pick-A-Brick? I saw another answer (https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/6021/15632) that says Pick-A-Brick has no limit.

Answer (score 3):

On the U.S. Website, it says that there is not a limit. Are you in, say, Great Britain or elsewhere in Europe? If so, maybe different regions have different limits due to availability and population.

Comment: Same here, but after you add 95 distinct bricks, it stops working, this also happens to me on the US website. There is no indication in the UI that 95 is the limit, and I can click on "Pick" for further bricks, but they never get added. The Chrome Inspector shows that the `AddToPABCart` returned an `Internal Server Error`. However, LEGO Support said: "_The item limits are there to keep your browsing session stable as it's a big task for most devices to handle_"

Comment: @BenediktKöppel I checked too and that is the case. However, that is also the same on the Great Britain website from what I can tell. Please check that to make sure that this is correct and not just user error.

Comment: yes, same happens on the German and Swiss stores. Given that it's a "Internal Server Error", I don't really believe the LEGO support that this is a deliberate limit, and it seems more like a technical glitch. I guess I'll have to file multiple PAB orders.

Comment: @BenediktKöppel OK. Thanks for helping me improve the answer!